# Attempting Leetcode problem and receiving Memory exceeded?

Tags: python, memory-management

I'm attempting to solve a Python problem on Leetcode which asks you to calculate and return the length of the longest substring containing unique characters for a given string. This is the code that I've test and seems to work but which the Leetcode site isn't accepting and is notifying me of a 'memory exceeded' error. Any idea how to solve this?

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """ First access all of the substrings """
        ls_subs = []
        unique_subs = []
        for i in range(len(s)):
            sub = s[i:]
            ls_subs.append(sub)

        """ Build versions of the substrings which contain unique chars """
        for sub in ls_subs:
            counter = 0
            unique = ""
            while counter < len(sub) and sub[counter] not in unique:
                unique += sub[counter]
                counter += 1
            unique_subs.append(unique)


        """ Find the longest one """
        length = 0
        for sub in unique_subs:
            if len(sub) > length:
                length = len(sub)
        return length
```

Answer (score 1):

If LeetCode gets an error running your code against its full set of test cases when you click Submit, it should show you the test case your code failed on in the upper-left corner of the screen. If as I would suspect the error happened with a super-large string, then the test case data it shows you will be cut off, but there will be a "Details" link there you can click to see the full test case. So get the known-failing test case that way, and you can use it to debug your code. BTW, as you're only supposed to be returning the length of the longest unique sub, you don't need to be storing the unique subs at all -- just as you find each unique sub do something like `longest = max(longest, len(unique))` after first initializing longest to 0.